# How to listen to a hyperlinked sound sample without visiting a new page?

Tags: audio, browser, hyperlink

Wikipedia pages (for example) often include *hyperlinks* <sup>1</sup> to sound samples, indicated by a small loudspeaker icon ( [image: wikipedia sound-sample icon] ).  Usually, next to the icon, there's a hyperlink pointing to a sound file.

For example, at the top of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brno) there's one such link, pointing to [this sound file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Cs-Brno.ogg).

Some pages (e.g. those related to phonology or pronunciation) have dozens, maybe hundreds, of such links, and it quickly becomes tedious to have to visit a new page every time one listens to a sound sample.

Is there some way to listen to the sound without having to visit a new page?  IOW, is there a way to tell the browser: *play the sound that this link points to*?

(Solutions that require using a specific browser, possibly enhanced with an extension, are OK.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with "embedded" sound samples that are already shown equipped with a playback interface, such as the one labeled "Sample" on the right-hand side of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slovak_phonology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) or similar to write your own script that scans wikipedia pages for .ogg and .mp3 links, remove the href and write your own function to play the link as a stream